# Robot "bucking" while driving in reverse

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Doing the Slam experiments, my robot does this (see attachment) buckling or stuttering motion. What causes that?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300209/robot-%22bucking%22-while-driving-in-reverse/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-08-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-10**:
@pitosalas: I took the liberty of converting your video to a gif so we keep this question self-contained.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-10**:
Thanks. I couldn’t find a way to attach a video. Animated gif. Clever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sending two 'cmd_vel' topics?
If so, one might be sent correctly and one seems to be at zero speed.
Check the 'cmd_vel' topic through rqt_graph.

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2018-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-08-10**:
A typical case for this to happen is when there is still some teleop node running somewhere when starting autonomous navigation.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-10**:
@pyo I suspected this might be the case but didn’t immediately think of how to check. Thanks for tip. @felixwidmayer I suspect the same. I think I checked that I killed it but there might have been a zombie teleport process that was not fully killed.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-13**:
@pyo @felix-widmaier - I see "bucking" behavior when teleoping in reverse, with no other nodes or packages running. So the theory was good, it doesn't; really seem to apply. Rosnode list, shows this: rosout, rqt_gui_py_node_4440, turtlebot3_core, turtlebot3_lds, turtlebot3_diagnostics.Thoughts??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-14**:
Perhaps a screenshot of `rqt_graph` would be more informative. Be sure to create it when you're actually observing the behaviour in the video.

It's very likely that there is a node publishing zero-Twists.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-14**:
I will try but I am almost 100% sure because I looked at the graph and saw no-one publishing on cmd_vel.

I am suspecting that it is a weight distribution problem because it seems to change if I slide the battery around a little. It doesn't solve it but it seems more or less severe

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-14**:
Could also be there is no proper ramp-up of teleop velocity commands. I already commented on your #q300208 about how the TB2 addresses that.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-14**:
@gvdhoorn by all means you've been super helpful and I am grateful! The teleop code supplied (and I looked at the source) definitely does do a rampup. I assume it's correct but I can investigate to make sure it does what is stated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-14**:
re: investigate: that may be a bit much at this stage.

I would take a look at some of the msgs on the `/cmd_vel` topic (or whatever is being used on the TB3). Just use `rostopic echo /cmd_vel` when the robot is standing still (replace with appropriate topic). Then compare when teleopping.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-15**:
New data reported in a new question: https://answers.ros.org/question/300653/interpetting-a-stream-of-cmd_vels/